# How to solve the following optmization problem using KKT?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have a simple optmization problem, I just want to see how to do it using  Karush-Kuhn-Tucker to understand it better.

$$\max_{x, y}  x^2+xy+y^2$$
subject to:
$$x < y \leq 1$$

Comment: What is KKT?  Karush-Kuhn-Tucke?

Comment: Yes. Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Comment: I think there is no solution. function is convex and you want to maximize it which leads to unbounded above solution. for example consider the case $x=-n \quad n\in \Bbb N$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Furthermore, the maximization of a convex function is not a convex optimization problem, so it shouldn't be tagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try solving $\max_{x\leq1,y\leq1}x^2+xy+y^2$ and pick solutions that satisfy $x<y$ (if any). Why? Since KKT do not deal with strict inequality constraints. Also, you problem has no solution (set $x=y-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$ and send $y\rightarrow-\infty$).

If the constraint is $0\leq x<y\leq1$, then my remark about KKT not dealing with strict inequalities still applies.

If the constraint is $0\leq x\leq y\leq1$, then the KKT approach is to split this series of inequalities into constraints that can be written in terms of $g_{i}(x,y)\leq c$ where $g_{i}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. That is, into five constraints $-x\leq0$, $x\leq1$, $-y\leq0$, $y\leq1$ and $x-y\leq0$.

Comment: I picked a bad example. What if the constraint is $0 \leq x < y \leq 1$

Comment: This answer should have been a comment.

Comment: @Anon123 I added couple of lines for the alternative constraint.